# MySQL auto-increment problem on master-master replication , and the logic to solve it

Tags: mysql, database, replication

I had a auto-increment duplication issue for master-master replication.  Then, I set:

```
SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER = 99999;
```

This skips 9999 queries.  Then I did:

```
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
Slave_IO_Running: Yes
Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
```

And it seems to be running OK.

But, of course, since I skipped 99999 statements...if I make a change on Database 1, it will not reflect it on Database 2...until 99999 statements are passed. Correct?

Well...I created a script to automatically insert 999999 rows into a dummy table.  This should be more than enough , right?  And my 2 databases should be in sync again???

But, I am on my 3 millionth row, and it doesn't seem to be working.  My Database 2 still does not have these 3 million rows that I just created on Database 1.

Answer (score 2):

After you sync up the dbs, you can avoid this by setting each master to have a different offset when they auto-inc.

```
i.e. 
master-1 only creates ids as: 1,11,21,31,41...
master-2 only creates ids as: 2,12,22,32,42...

On master-1, add this to the my.cnf
auto_increment_increment = 10
auto_increment_offset = 1

on master-2, and this to the my.cnf
auto_increment_increment = 10
auto_increment_offset = 2
```

Now they will never collide.

Answer (score 1):

What I do in instances like this is:

- stop the slave (STOP SLAVE)
- drop the slave table that is out of sync
- stop the master (STOP MASTER)
- dump the MASTER table that is correct
- re-import the MASTER table into the SLAVE
- restart master and slave

Tables should now be back in sync.